# How can I present a pick list in a SharePoint 2010 External List form from an association in my BDC model?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

I have created associations between entities in my .Net assembly BCS model.  When I load the model into SharePoint and create external lists, I automatically get an External Item Picker control; enabling me to select an item from a list.

This is great because I don't have to program this pick list one way or another...

The problem is whenever I modify the form in InfoPath, the External Item Picker seems to break.  When I select an item using the External Item Picker (in the InfoPath form) I get an error message "There has been an error while processing the form".  This message is displayed as soon as I select an item and try to leave the field; WITHOUT submitting the form.

Can anyone tell me why the External Item Picker breaks whenever I modify and publish the list form from InfoPath 2010?

It's driving me nuts!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into the same issue, and found the following answer:
It's a bug from the August cumulative update.
[Source](http://www.mattjimison.com/blog/2011/10/28/infopath-error-the-control-must-be-in-the-control-tree-of-a-page/)

I am in the process of installing the February CU to see if it has the solution.

Comment: February 2k12 CU installed, Had some issues on my Dev environment, where profile services didn't want to start again.. But in all others it worked after a bit of troubleshooting.